# Converting into PDO

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

Good evening everyone! 
I need your help again. Please bear with me because I am very new to this. Hoping for your understanding. So, I am having a project on oop and pdo. I am having quite hard time converting this into pdo.. Here is my code..

bookReserve.php

```
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
     $oldstock=$row['quantity'];
    }

    $newstock = $oldstock-$quantity;
```

Here's what i've done

```
    while($row = $code->fetchAll())
    {
      $oldstock=$row['quantity'];
    }

    $newstock = $oldstock-$quantity;
```

Is that even correct?
And for the oop part, after this while loop I have a query to execute.

```
    $sql="update books set no_copies = '$newstock' where book_title = '$book_title'";
```

Here's what I've done trying to convert it into pdo

```
public function bookreserve2($q)
{
  $q = "UPDATE books SET quantity WHERE = $newstock where book_title = '$book_title'"; 
  $stmt = $this->con->prepare($q);
  $stmt->execute(array(':newstock'=>$newstock));
  $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  return $result;
}
```

Again, Is that even the correct converted query? 
and how would I call $newstock?

P.S. my oop class and pdo is placed in a separate file. Thought this might help.

Thanks

Comment: You are not showing enough context here.

Comment: I am trying to convert things into pdo and I don't know if Im doing it correct.

Comment: Well does it work? Are you having a specific problem, or just looking for advice on best approach (i.e. a code review), in which case posting on codereview.stackexchange.com would be your best bet. Just make sure you include more context.  Just seeing a query and the portion of code where you are fetching your result set is not enough information upon which to give feedback on your approach.

Comment: This should help: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: You have `update books set no_copies =` in your first query, but `UPDATE books SET quantity` in your second? Are you updating `no_copies` or `quantity`?

Comment: @MikeBrant okay sir. I'll try to change this question after I have the tested conversion.

Comment: @Sean sorry, I forgot to change it, its quantity.

Answer (score 1):

You are not including your query parameters in your function, and your query has syntax errors (extra WHERE) and you are directly inserting your values not using placeholders.

It should look something like -

```
public function bookreserve2($newstock,$book_title)
{
  $q = "UPDATE books SET quantity = :newstock WHERE book_title = :book_title"; 
  $stmt = $this->con->prepare($q);
  $stmt->execute(array(':newstock'=>$newstock,':booktitle'=>$book_title));
  if($stmt){
      return true;
  }
  else {
      return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh i see. Thanks. 
After tweaking the codes a bit.. I got this error "Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object" what does this means

Comment: That means what you called `fetchAll()` on is a non-object - most likely that your query has failed. You will always want to check it your query is successful before using it - ie. `if($stmt){..`

Comment: @user3345570 Check out that teresko gave you (in the comments), if you are too lazy then check [this script](https://github.com/simon-eq/pdowrapper) made exclusively for lazy people